# No valid JREs found for execution environment "JavaSE-1.8"

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, wildfly

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and I have installed OpenJdk as my Java JDK, indeed if in the terminal i write `java -version` the output will be:

```
openjdk version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Also in Eclipse in Preferences > Installed JREs I can see "jdk14.0.2" as "Standard VW". Now I'm trying to install Wildfly 14 from a my personal directory but when i start the guided procedure i see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQsa3.png).
I also tried to chose or add the JRE 1.8 in the build path options of the project but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

A sub-dialog of "Installed JREs" is "Execution Environments".  If you look at that dialog and click on the "JavaSE-1.8" entry, you will see the list of installed JREs for that execution environment. In this case, I assume there will be no checked entries there.

It would be logical to install a Java 8 distribution and reference it here, and set your JDK 14.0.2 distro in the "JavaSE-14" environment.  I don't know what Wildfly execution requirements are.

Comment: I solved because I have installed JRE in /usr/java instead of /usr/local/java